# div on top of another div when dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 2 divs with a jquery resizable and draggable feature and they work fine. My question is how can I make the 2 divs overlap each other when they are in use. To elaborate right now frame 2 is always on top of frame 1 how can I make frame 1 on top of frame 2 when I drag it over it and frame 2 on top of frame 1 when it's dragged over. Is this possible? Something like `on active` state. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $framewrap1 = $('.framewrap1');

  $framewrap1
    .resizable({
      handles: 'n, e, s, w, sw, se, nw, ne'
    })
    .draggable({

    });
});

jQuery($ => {
  let $framewrap2 = $('.framewrap2');

  $framewrap2
    .resizable({
      handles: 'n, e, s, w, sw, se, nw, ne'
    })
    .draggable({

    });
});
```

```css
.framewrap1 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 150px; 
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%
}

.framewrap2 {
  background-color: brown;
  width: 150px; 
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">


<div class="framewrap1" id="framewrap1">
</div>
<div class="framewrap2" id="framewrap1">
</div>
```